# vs code debugger (lldb) does not show correct value

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, lldb

When I view `result` in visual studio code debugging it does not show the correct value `10` but the unitialized value, caused by the outer scoped `result` (below the loop). The program does prints the 10 correctly of course. Is this a GDB bug or a VSCode bug?

```
int main()
{

    {
        int result = 0;
        result += 6 + 4;
        printf("result: %d\n", result);
    }

    int result;

}
```

[image]

Comment: which OS, compiler / version ? which VSCode version ? which C++ plugin ?

Comment: **Pro Tip:** You're declaring the same variable `result` in each iteration, take that out from the loop and put that above it, otherwise you'll keep seeing 10s 12 times in output. Also, the `result` at the end is useless. Lastly, the debugger for me seems to be working fine.

Comment: Have you turned off compiler optimizations before debugging? With aggressive optimizations, there might not even be a `result` variable in your program.

Comment: This is a VSCode bug. GDB is perfectly capable of showing the correct value.

Comment: @RohanBari It's an example to demonstrate the bug, the variables are not useless. Ignore the for-loop, it is only there for scoping. If you think the debugger works fine showing -272630336 when the variable is 10, it's hard to discuss the bug :)

Comment: @HAL9000 yes, there are no compiler optimalizations. I use the official Microsoft cpp-extension, I posted it to their forums as well. (vscode version 1.43.1, Mac OS 10.15.7)

Comment: Debugger is LLDB by the way. They are investigating it at vscode, so curious to see what gives.

Comment: Xcode (which also uses lldb) gets this right.  lldb has two API's for getting locals: "get all locals that are visible at the current PC", and "get all the variables that are alive in some scope containing the current PC."  You generally use the latter to fill the Locals view, but if you are doing flyovers you need to use the former API, since you don't want to show shadowed variables.  I'm guessing they use the second API then just pick off the first entry that has the right name...